# ¿Cómo ocultar o bloquear la ruta de un proyecto en xampp y bloquear la carpeta para que nadie sin permiso pueda acceder?

Tags: php, html, xampp

Alguien me puede ayudar con esta duda de bloquear (si se puede decir así) la ruta de mi proyecto en la barra de direcciones de mi navegador digamos que tengo **127.0.0.1/Proyecto/carpeta1/formulario1.php** a que se pudiera ver así **127.0.0.1/Proyecto/carpeta1** o **Proyecto/carpeta1** y como hacer para proteger mi código para que nadie pueda manipularlo sin permiso.

Comment: Haz intentado con htaccess? Puede ser una buena alternativa.

Comment: @ArmandoVázquez me podrías explicar como o un ejemplo?